# Calling HTMLPurifier->getHTMLDefinition() is changing HTMLPurifier's behaviour

Tags: php, htmlpurifier

I'm using HTMLPurifier to sanitize some HTML I'm getting from a form. However when I call `getHTMLDefinition()` on my config it causes `HTMLPurifier->purify()` to throw a warning.

Here's my setup:

```
$HPConfig = HTMLPurifier_Config::createDefault();
$HPConfig->set('Cache.SerializerPath', APPLICATION_ROOT.'/forums/cache/HtmlPurifier');
$HPConfig->set('HTML.Doctype', 'XHTML 1.0 Transitional');
$HPConfig->set('HTML.AllowedElements', ['p','br','img','i','b']);
$HPConfig->set('HTML.AllowedAttributes', ['href','style']);
$HPConfig->set('CSS.AllowedProperties', 'text-align');

$HPConfig->set('HTML.DefinitionID', 'myapp-text.html');
$HPConfig->set('HTML.DefinitionRev', 2);
$def = $HPConfig->getHTMLDefinition(true);

$HtmlPurifier = new HTMLPurifier($HPConfig); 
$text = $HtmlPurifier->purify($text);
```

When I use the above code my script throws this warning:

```
Warning: Global attribute 'href' is not supported in any elements (for information on implementing this, see the support forums)  in /var/...
```

However, if I simply remove the `$def = $HPConfig->getHTMLDefinition(true);` line the warning disappears. What does the `getHTMLDefinition()` method do that causes HTMLPurifier's behaviour to change? and is there a way to prevent it from happening?

Comment: What does it `getHTMLDefinition()` do? Obviously it alters the state of `HTMLPurifier_Config`. That obviously should not happen, and should be considered as a bug. To workaround this try setting `getHTMLDefinition()`'s arguments both to false.

Comment: Good idea @DavidY, unfortunately that didn't work and actually ended up breaking my custom attribute definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the warning is right: href isn't supported for all elements, so you have to say `a.href` to allow `href` on `a` tags.